# How can I print a set of names in Javascript the first time the script runs followed by a prompt the second time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

This is the exercise:

Create a small program that contains a list of employee
names. Print out the list of names when the program runs
the first time. Prompt for an employee name and remove
that specific name from the list of names. Display the
remaining employees, each on its own line.

Example Output

---

**There are 5 employees:**

John Smith
 
Jackie Jackson
Chris Jones
Amanda Cullen
Jeremy Goodwin

Enter an employee name to remove: Chris Jones

**There are 4 employees:**

John Smith
Jackie Jackson
Amanda Cullen
Jeremy Goodwin

---

Constraint

• Use an array or list to store the names.

This is what I've tried so far (although it prompts for the name to be removed as soon as the script loads, rather than after the first 5 names have been printed).

```js
var nameToRemove;
var employee = ["John Smith", "Jackie Jackson", "Chris Jones", "Amanda Cullen", "Jeremy Goodwin"];
var i;

document.write("There are " + employee.length + " employees: <br><br>");
for (i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
    document.write(employee[i] + "<br>");
}

nameToRemove = employee.indexOf(prompt("Enter an employee name to remove:"));

if (nameToRemove > -1) {
  employee.splice(nameToRemove, 1);
}

document.write("<br>There are " + employee.length + " employees: <br><br>");
for (i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
    document.write(employee[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: @DJ012 Please [edit] your question and add your code

Comment: It's up there now

Comment: @DJ012 What is the part you're having issues with?

Comment: When the code runs, you don't see the initial list of 5 names, all you see is the box prompting for the name to be removed. The list of names should be shown before the box appears asking what name the user wants to remove

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `document.write` to write the elements of the array to the document, it takes a little more time to reflect it to the user while the content has already been written to the DOM. I used the same code but instead of using `document.write` I used `console.log` and it worked as expected.

The only workaround I could find in your case is to use the `setTimeout` function.

[**Check out this fiddle to see it in action**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohit0094arora/w2sn0wuv/)

Also, the dialogue boxes such as alert and prompt  stop the execution of the wholw javascript until an action is taken, this makes the reflection of the written content only possible after you click cancel or okay on the prompt box.

Answer (score 1):

probably is because javascript is asynchronous, you should use callback function to be sure that the first code is executed before running the rest.quick reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

on the other side you can do the prompt inside the loop for the last element:

pseudo code:

```
for (i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
    document.write(employee[i] + "<br>");
    if (i == employee.length) {
        //do the prompt
    }
}
```